# Get distinct coordinates from mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my Mongo model:

```
Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, index: true, ref: 'user'},
    date: {type: Number, index: true},
    coords: {type: [Number], index: '2dsphere', required: true} //not distinct
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve *distinct* coordinates by date in the following format:

```
[[long, lat],[long, lat],[long, lat], ..., [long, lat]]
```

I wrote something like that:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
var days = req.params.days || 365;
db.model('activity').aggregate([
    {$match: {date: {$gte: getDatesFromNumDays(days)[0], $lte: getDatesFromNumDays(days)[1]}}},
    {$group: {
        _id: '$coords'
    }},
], function (err, result) { ... }
```

What, unfortunately, returns me

```
[{"_id":[69.60151471655979,42.32299082108329]},{"_id":[-121.9339648456008,37.37375532540034]},{"_id":[-121.907453583667,37.36068282279872]...]
```

What am I missing here? How to have array of arrays in the output?

Answer (score 1):

The aggregation framework as with all forms of query that return MongoDB documents must stick to the basic "key/value" form of results.

The only command that will return simply an array of singular field results is [**`.distinct()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)

```js
db.model('activity').distinct(
    'coords',
    { "date": { 
      "$gte": getDatesFromNumDays(days)[0], 
      "$lte": getDatesFromNumDays(days)[1]
    }},
    function(err,result) {
     // result is a array of the field values only
    }
);
```

--

Simple distinct example:

```js
db.col.insert({ "a": [[1,2],[3,4]] })
db.col.insert({ "a": [[1,2],[5,6]] })
```

Output from `.distinct()`:

```js
db.col.distinct("a")
[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6 ] ]
```

Comment: distinct's output is just a plain array of elements, note, I need an array of arrays. Google maps expects something like [[long, lat],[long, lat],[long, lat], ..., [long, lat]].

I my current implementation, I shape the output on nodejs level to get the needed format, however, this adds 650ms delay to the response

Comment: @user5075806 No `.distinct()` outputs "distinct values of a field" in a plain array. Which is what you asked for since your "values of a field" are in this case "arrays" themselves. See the basic example added.